# How to implement if statement within the specific row and column of text file?

Tags: c#

I have text file like

```
Time    amplitude   index
1       0,25        25
2       0,68        28
3       -2,5        69
4       2,5         94
5       3           45
6       5           26
```

What in need to get is this.

```
Time    amplitude   index   classified
1       0,25        25      1
2       0,68        28      1
3       -2,5        69      2
4       2,5         94      1
5       3           45      1
6       5           26      1
```

It need to write additional column (classified) with statement 1 (column classified) we classifies that amplitude is increasing during the time, with statement 2 (column classified) we classifies that amplitude is decreasing during the time.  I have a big text file and it need to be written in new text file.  I was try with code like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader dat = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textBox2.Text, true);
    {
    while (!dat.EndOfStream)
    {
        string mainLine1 = dat.ReadLine();
        string[] originalLine1 = mainLine1.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        for (int i = 1; i < mainLine1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (originalLine1[i] > originalLine1[i-1])
            {
                sw.WriteLine(originalLine1[0] + "\t" + originalLine1[1] + "\t"+"1");
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

I know that the code is not right but that is what I figured it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the value of the `classified` column should be? The way I understand it, it should be 1 if `amplitude` is positive, 2 if it's negative, is that correct? If so, what should happen when amplitude is 0?

Comment: Its means if number is decreasing then is 2 if numbers are incising then is 1. No mether if the nember is negative or positive. 
If its 0 then depends if previous is classified like 2 then is 2. If is classified like 1 then is 1.

Comment: Why you don't save the previous amplitude element with the current element? If it's lower you'll print 2 either 1. If it's the first element you'll compare it with 0. If lower add 2 either 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solve the problem. If Someone need it.

Example tex file:

1

2

3

2

1

-1

-2

-3

-2

-1

1

2

3

Need to get additional column and write tex file:
1       1

2   1

3   1

2   2

1   2

-1  3

-2  3

-3  3

-2  4

-1  4

1   1

2   1

3   1

Code

```
string niz;
                        int j=0;
                        string[] vrstica, vrstica_prej=null;
                        while (!dat.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            niz = dat.ReadLine();
                            vrstica = niz.Split('\t');
                            j++;
                            if (j < 2)
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(vrstica[0] + "\t" + vrstica[1] + "\t" + "0");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                double a = Convert.ToDouble(vrstica[0]);
                                double a_pre = Convert.ToDouble(vrstica_prej[0]);
                                if (a > a_pre && a > 0)
                                {sw.WriteLine(vrstica[0] + "\t" + "1"); }
                                else if (a < a_pre && a > 0)
                                {sw.WriteLine(vrstica[0] + "\t" + "2"); }
                                else if (a < a_pre && a < 0)
                                {sw.WriteLine(vrstica[0] +"\t" + "3"); }
                                else if (a > a_pre && a < 0)
                                {sw.WriteLine(vrstica[0] + "\t" + "4"); }
                            }
                            vrstica_prej = vrstica;
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Close();
```

I hope someone will be glad for it.